# Android (Xamarin) gridlayout in linearlayout

Tags: android, xamarin, layout

I'm working on an android application where the main menu looks something like this:

[Main menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZC2v.png)

To do this, I'm using a linearlayout to seperate the screen 40/60 - accomplished using layout_weight for the height.

Then, I split the 60% portion of the linearlayout using a gridlayout and placed buttons into the grids. However, the screen comes up as completely empty. Here's my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:rowCount="2"
            android:columnCount="2">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="Click me"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_blue" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="Click me"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_blue" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="Click me"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_blue" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="Click me"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_blue" />
        </GridLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
<!--Other code-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've thought of that as well, but thought that gridlayout is a more efficient performance wise, and also doesn't repeat code. In the event I need more buttons, for example 8 buttons, then I would require 4 linear layouts. Would that be acceptable?

I think what you need is [Grid View](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) with `android:numColumns="2"` and then use adapter to fill your buttons in each cell.

Here is tutorial about using `GridView` in Xamarin.Android and you can have a look: [Grid View](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/grid_view/).

Comment: Similarly to linearlayout, I would require a grid view for each row right? Doesn't my previous comment still stand then?

Comment: @Ryalis, no, I think you didn't understand what is a `GridView` control, it's not a linearlayout or a gridlayout, it's like `ListView` but can have several column in each row. So you don't need a `GridView` for each row, you just need one `GridView` for the whole layout where you want to add your button. Please just check the official doc I provided.

Comment: I've looked at the documentation and some examples and will give it a try. I'll update later if I managed to get it to work. Thank you.

Comment: What would be the best way to create the layout in axml? Or has it have to be done programmatically?

Comment: @Ryalis, you mean create a `GridView`? You can do it in axml, the adapter and the data should be done programmatically. The last doc in my answer shows how to do it in xamarin.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But I'm trying to keep my UI to axml. My question was whether there was a good alternative to achieving what the gridview can do, without without needing to have to do it programmatically.

Comment: @Ryalis, I think no, the data need to be added to `GridView` in code behind.

Answer (score 1):

why you don't use a Simple LinearLayout like this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="356dp"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="76dp">

            <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="73dp"
                android:id="@+id/button3" />

            <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="76dp"
                android:id="@+id/button2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="73dp"
                android:id="@+id/button1" />

            <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="76dp"
                android:id="@+id/button4" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!--Other code-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've thought of that as well, but thought that gridlayout is a more efficient performance wise, and also doesn't repeat code. In the event I need more buttons, for example 8 buttons, then I would require 4 linear layouts. Would that be acceptable?